# Use htaccess to rewrite old site urls

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, migration

I just moved a site to Wordpress.

The old sites urls for posts looked like this http://www.example.com/view-story.php?sid=437
Wordpress looks like this http://www.example.com/?p=437

I need to redirect any requests to the old url to the new wordpress url.

Can anyone tell me what I need to put in the htaccess file for the site?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^sid=([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^view-story.php ?p=%1 [R=302,L]
```

change 302 to 301 once you get it working.

Comment: That works perfectly.
It's like a foreign language to me, how can I learn about .htaccess, I've tried the docs and some sites but still find it like some dark art, is there a resource you'd recommend?